# automatic hadoop services Start

Tags: hadoop, centos

iam using centos 7 and i want to make hadoop services working by dynamic way
i mean i want to automate the process of issuing start-all.sh command
to be executed automatically after boot of centos

i had made the following script and let it called start-hadoop.sh (/root/start-hadoop.sh)

```
/etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh

/usr/local/hadoop/sbin/start-dfs.sh
```

which sould start hadoop-services

i had  trired  to give this script execute permissions as root user  and to put this script directory in the file rc.local

which is found under the path /etc/rc.d/rc.local of course after giving it 
execute permissions  but it is not executed at boot
 any help please and are there any better ways

Comment: Are you able to find any solution for this ?